Ktor won't get response body from response.body()
This is my problem (Logcat):
I  HttpClient: REQUEST: http://...
I  METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
I  COMMON HEADERS
I  -> Accept: application/json
I  -> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
I  -> Content-Type: application/json 
I  CONTENT HEADERS
I  -> Content-Length: 0
I  BODY Content-Type: null
I  BODY START
I  
I  BODY END
I  well well wellnull
I  HttpClient: RESPONSE: 401 Unauthorized
I  METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
I  FROM: http://...
I  COMMON HEADERS
I  -> cache-control: no-cache, private
I  -> connection: keep-alive
I  -> content-type: application/json
I  -> date: Wed, 14 Aug 2024 03:43:27 GMT
I  -> server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
I  -> transfer-encoding: chunked
I  -> x-android-received-...: 1723607006217
I  -> x-android-response-source: NETWORK 401
I  -> x-android-selected-protocol: http/1.1
I  -> x-android-sent-...: 1723607006056
I  BODY Content-Type: application/json
I  BODY START
I  {"message":"User already logged in!","token":"......"}
I  BODY END

This is my first time using Ktor because i need to use it. Idk why Ktor getting response body from request instead of response, the first one is null (black space between BODY START and BODY END) and the 2nd one is not null with message "User already logged in!", and i need to get the 2nd one.
Just like the screenshot, I've tried to check it with println and it return null ("well well wellnull"). I don't know how to get the second one that i marked green.
This is my client:
val ktorHttpClient = HttpClient{
    install(ContentNegotiation){
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }

    install(Logging){
        logger = Logger.SIMPLE
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }

    install(HttpTimeout){
        requestTimeoutMillis = 15000
    }
}

And this is my repository:
suspend fun userlogin(theurl: String, userrequest: LoginRequest): LoginResponse{
        val response = try {
            ktorHttpClient.post("${theurl}/login"){
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                parameter("username", userrequest.username)
                parameter("password", userrequest.password)
            }
        } catch (e: UnresolvedAddressException){
            //ktorHttpClient.close()
            return LoginResponse(message = e.message)
        } catch (e: SerializationException) {
            //ktorHttpClient.close()
            return LoginResponse(message = e.message)
        }

        //ktorHttpClient.close()
        return when(response.status.value){
            in 200..299 ->{
                response.body()
            }
            else -> response.body()
        }
    }

EDIT:
Okay so i already got what happened. The "response.body()" does not return the body that contains "message" and "token" but instead the URL and status code. I need to get that message and token and return it as LoginResponse (serializable data class)

@KenWhite so how do i copy-paste logcat from my android studio? should i copy paste it manually row by row?

I see you figured it out before I could answer. :-)

@KenWhite yeah, i copy-pasted it manually.. didn't know the upload image feature is useless. Thanks

Uploading images is fine, when an image is necessary to demonstrate a problem. A text error message does not need an image. If you read the link I provided before, you'd know why images are to be used only when absolutely necessary. I'll post it again for you: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@KenWhite yeah i know, it was a joke, sorry, i've red it. I just thought logcat image is okay since it doesn't need correction and doesn't contain error. The one that need corection is the function.

Images should be used only as a last resort, when there's no other way to demonstrate a problem. That long list of reasons in that linked page tells you why.

What does the userlogin method return? What's expected to be returned?

@AlekseiTirman thank you for the reply, i was trying to get the response body but the response.body() not showing the response body() but instead just URL and status code. I need to return that message and token, and put it inside serializable data class called "Login Response"

Okay, so turns out im getting the wrong data. I thought response.body() is the JSON string i got, turns out it was not and it will always return null bcuz response.body() only contains url and status code.
So i got the string json from response.call.response.bodyAsText(). And then i convert it or decode it into data class using:
val loginJson: LoginResponse = Json.decodeFromString( respon.call.response.bodyAsText())

Then i return "loginJson".

Is it wrong or anyone has better answer that more shorter or ethical? If no i will mark it as the answer.
